# how to get the value of an arrow function in node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, socket.io

I want to get the value of the variable "final" to be able to send to the frontend through sockets

My code

```
const admin = database.collection("admin").onSnapshot(documento =>{
     const final = documento.docs.map((doc) =>({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}))
     return final
})

const alerts = admin()

console.log(alerts);

//sockets
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Alguien se ha conectado con Sockets');

    socket.emit('alerts', alerts);
    socket.on('new-alert', function (data) {
        alerts.push(data);
        io.sockets.emit('alerts', alerts);
    });

}); 
//sockets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the necessary logic to be executed when `onSnapshot` is called.

```
const admin = database.collection("admin").onSnapshot(documento =>{
     const final = documento.docs.map((doc) =>({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}))
     // Code that uses final here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah my final code is

```
//sockets
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Alguien se ha conectado con Sockets');


    const admin = database.collection("admin").onSnapshot(documento =>{
        const alerts = documento.docs.map((doc) =>({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}))

        socket.emit('alerts', alerts);
        socket.on('new-alert', function (data) {
            alerts.push(data);
            io.sockets.emit('alerts', alerts);
        });


    })

}); 
//sockets
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.